# mysql workbench crashed and wont turn on again. Specific error is shown

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i was working on mysql workbench and suddenly it just froze. So I closed it from task manager and killed the process.
Upon trying to reopen it, i get this message -

```
mysql workbench encountered a problem ...db_utils.pyc is denied
```

It wont turn on again. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows try Running as administrator.  If using Linux make sure the permissions are still set properly.